# Help: Java error message re: incompatible types

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm writing a program for my intro to Java class.  I'm getting an error message, and I can't figure out what exactly it's telling me or how to resolve the issue.  This is the message:

```
packageCost.java:17: incompatible types
found   : void
required: java.lang.String
                input = System.out.print("Please enter the weight of " +
                                        ^
packageCost.java:22: incompatible types
found   : void
required: java.lang.String
                input = System.out.print("How many miles is this " +
                                        ^
2 errors
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempting to assign a String to "System.out.print("Please enter..");

System.out.print returns "void" which is not String, thus incompatible types.

It looks like your trying to do console input.  You could use a Scanner to do this.

Try something like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter input: ");
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

Read about Scanner class, Just google it.

Comment: If I had the rep, -1 for being rude. We all have to start somewhere - stackoverflow is not just for current professionals. At least this isn't a homework question.

Comment: Was not trying to be rude, that sounded more rude than I intended.  I spent three years as a Teaching Assistant, and I'm just saying Programming is a difficult thing to learn without studying and paying attention in class.  :)

Comment: No worries- I'm taking an intro to java class online, so i'm basically given reading material and have to teach myself.  We only covered scanner class last week, and i was writing an if else if input program and neglected to add the scanner.

Answer (score 3):

[System.out.print](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) does not return anything and you are trying to collect its return value in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

better:

```
String input = System.console().readLine("Please enter the ..");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner won't work without declaring at the top of the document:

import java.util.Scanner;